# Websocket Messages Throwing StackOverFlow Exception, WebSocketSharp, .NET 6

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, .net-6.0, websocket-sharp

I am working on a desktop application that connects to the League of Legends LCU API. I am using my own modified version of the PoniLCU Library to interact with the client. One issue I cannot seem to get around is the handling of Websocket events.

It works perfectly fine, except for when the program is running and the League Client is not, upon then starting the League Client. Not to long after a connection is made, a StackOverFlow exception is then thrown. This issue is also discussed on the PoniLCU Repo too. Here is my method:

```cs
        private void TryConnect()
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsConnected) return;

                var status = GetLeagueStatus();
                if (status == null) return;

                ProcessInfo = status;
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("riot:" + status.Item2);
                Client!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                SocketConnection = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:" + status.Item3 + "/", "wamp");
                SocketConnection.SetCredentials("riot", status.Item2, true);

                SocketConnection.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                SocketConnection.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

                // Add event handlers for OnOpen and OnClose
                SocketConnection.OnOpen += (sender, e) => OnWebSocketOpen();
                SocketConnection.OnClose += (sender, e) => OnWebSocketClose(e.Code, e.Reason, e.WasClean);
                SocketConnection.OnMessage += (sender, e) => onWebSocketMessage(sender!, e);

                SocketConnection.Connect();
                SocketConnection.Send($"[5, \"OnJsonApiEvent\"]");

                ProcessInfo = status;
                IsConnected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ProcessInfo = null;
                IsConnected = false;
                if (!IsConnected) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Exception occurred trying to connect to League of Legends: {e.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

And by removing this line:

```cs
SocketConnection.Send($"[5, \"OnJsonApiEvent\"]");
```

The issue no longer occurs.

When the client is running, the events work fine and I can view them in my HandleMessage method being written to the output through Debug.Writeline.

I have tried inside of the HandleMessage method checking for duplicate events, but I realise now this likely doesn't mean anything as it's probably an issue before this stage. Or just with the sent events in general.

I have tried adding a Thread.Sleep delay in the hope of slowing down all of the requests. As on first launch the client produces a lot of requests in the output. As well as the connection to the client occurs twice. I have a message box that appears OnOpen, and this message box is displayed twice, along with the OnDisconnect one too. So I thought simply delaying the program might help with this but to no avail.

Another reason for my above thought was that when I launch the client with my program open, if I dont click on the message boxes for some time. I avoid the StackOverFlow exception, but then I also lose any events being displayed in the output from the handle message method. To note without my MessageBox the issue still pertains. The original Library has no such thing and still encounters the same issue.

This isn't my strong suite, I initially simply removed anything to do with the events. But I actually now would like to handle them so I know what the client is doing in the moment to display my programs options accordingly. I am not to sure where to go from here except using a different Library to WebSocketSharp but I could not implement anything that worked for me.

Further Note on the Repo it is mentioned about it being a .NET 6.0 issue. I am not sure if it is worth me downgrading or upgrading to avoid it like so. I did try downgrade but could not get it working after.

.NET 6, WebSocketSharp Library

Comment: An exception cannot be caught twice.  If a library has an exception handler you need to add a THROW in the library so you application code will also see the exception.  You are sending JSON so it the HTTP header for content-type also JSON?

Comment: I am not entirely sure where I would implement that throw. Try block on .Send call does nothing. Exception is thrown in Buffer.cs with these details "System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
"
And also this "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll"

I believe the content type is all Json yes, it is from what I can tell capturing the requests made by the client locally

Comment: Can the error be detected in the PoniLCU Library?  That is where the throw would need to be located.  Where is code Buffer.cs located?

Comment: The SocketConnection.Send(etc.); line seems to be the one that generates the error. That is already surrounded in a Try block. Without that line of code exceptions are ever thrown.

I also placed a try block in the handle message method which writes all the events to the debug output. But again the error occurs in Buffer.cs and the output states System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

One thing to note on running the application the output does print
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but not sure why

Comment: You need an exception handler in buffer.cs with a throw.  Can you add code to buffer.cs to check that the directory exists before the error occurs?  Then if directory does not exist add a throw or return an error status.

Comment: I placed on in buffer.cs but didnt obtain any extra information. I now also got an error in MemoryStream.cs on method Capacity

Comment: You must be getting further in the code.  When directory doesn't exist you should return from code instead of continuing.  Before you were getting an exception when directory wasn't found. Now you are getting past first exception and getting another exception.

Comment: Even with no change whatsoever the place where the exception is thrown is consistently changing. Is there any alternatives to using Websocketsharp that can be used to replace with the same functionality. As I believe the error will likely fall on to the websocketsharp library or the league client. And I cant really do much about them anyways. its just simply the websocket events that im after here, everything else works fine about it

Comment: Don't know.  Once exception fail and is captured, the parent cannot detect the failure unless a throw is done.  Or you prevent the exception by doing a test so you do not get the exception.  You should be getting the same failure every time.  If you are getting multiple failures you are probably getting a timeout as well as the reported error.  Increasing the timeout may get consistent results.

Comment: Definitely could be the case, might explain why I was able to dodge the exception by waiting on pressing ok on my message boxes as multiple spawn in. I did notice on nuget there is a websocketsharp fork with a fix for .net 6. But I am unable to get this package working at all, with my .Connect() call always giving me a null object reference exception. Applying a try throw there didnt give me any further information either. So its all just a pain really hah